# Identify the liars

Tags: code-golf

There are \$a\$ honest man(always tell the truth), \$b\$ dishonest man(always tell lie), and \$c\$ random man(tell random Y/N). How many times at least should you ask one of them a yes/no question about who they are, to guarantee you get knowledge of who they are? You may assume that it's possible.

Test cases:

```
(a,b,c) -> ans
(1,1,0) -> 1
(1,1,1) -> 3
(0,0,2) -> 0
```

Notes:

- I don't know if there's clever way, but anyway brute-force work
- It's same if you can ask any expression without referring current or future ask. If you ask them "what will A answer if I ask B" the answer is just "(A is liar) xor B". "Did A tell lie when answering B" is just "(A's answer) xor B".
- Actually it's possible to identify them iff there are less than half of random answerer, or an edge case that all are random answerers. Only considering honest and random, if there are more honest than random, ask them same question and do a majority vote gets answer to the question. If there are same honest and random, and random tell as if they are honest and real honest are random, you can't tell the difference.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18940/)

Comment: I don't think the rules about what types of questions can be asked are very clear.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Is [the one by user202729](https://pybin.pw/AP30-guauPKExtWVm_4Vf71Ui9j9) clearer?

Comment: I can't open that link currently, but if it's one of those formal specs then most likely not.

Comment: @mbomb007 Notes 3

Comment: Can you add some more test cases for larger numbers?

Comment: @Jonah I don't know if there's clever way, and larger cases may cost lots of time in silliest way

Comment: @mbomb007 it is actually possible to be 100% certain of who is who if you have one of each, including someone telling random answers. [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKvjIsyYng8&ab_channel=TED-Ed) explains it well

Comment: Should we assume that each of the men knows which of the other men is liar/honest/random? And that they all know what they all know, etc, to infinity, giving them common knowledge?

Comment: @xnor It's public that they know each other